# Multivariate Distribution & Bayes Rule

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bayes-theorem

Suppose I have that an unknown vector, x,  where x is drawn from the following distribution$ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ ~ $N\bigl(0, \bigl[\begin{matrix}
\sigma^2_1 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2\\ & \sigma_2^2
\end{matrix} \bigr]\bigr) $

Further suppose that I am given a value $s$ such that:

$s=x_2 + \epsilon$,

where $\epsilon$~$N(0,v)$

I need to calculate $E[x_1 - x_2 | s]$

Here is my answer, but I don't know if it's correct:

From standard Bayes rule, I have that $E[x_2 | s]=ws ; w=\frac{\sigma^2_2}{\sigma^2_2+v}$ (1)

Furthermore, I also know that $E[x_1 | x_2]=\frac{\rho\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}x_2$ (2)

Do equations (1) and (2) imply that:

$E[x_1 - x_2 | s] = w(\frac{\rho\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}-1)s$?

Comment: I have confirmed my answer. $E[x_1|S_1] = E_{x_2}[E[x_1|x_2]|S_1]$ by LIE, and the solution easily follows.